# How to upgrade Flutter without breaking my app

Tags: flutter

I have a fairly complex app written in Flutter, that has the requirement to save data, photos and video whilst offline, and can sync when there is an internet connection.

Now I haven't updated this working app for 6 months, is it safe to upgrade to latest version of Flutter along with all of the plugins I am using ?

Running on a iMac with iPhone X connected for debug ( Android emulators struggle - I need a proper device for testing before publishing app )

Flutter 1.2.1-pre.101

```
pubspec.yaml

  intl: ^0.15.7
  sqflite: ^0.12.2+1
  image_picker: ^0.4.5
  path_provider: ^0.5.0
  image: ^2.0.6
  date_format: ^1.0.6
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  map_view:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/Eimji/flutter_google_map_view.git
  location: ^2.3.2
  xml: ^3.3.1
  camera: ^0.5.4+2
  video_player: ^0.10.0
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
```

Should I create a new isolated install of Flutter and upgrade the plugins ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably only the plugins which are developed by Flutter Team will break because they have added the latest AndroidX support. You can migrate your project to support the AndroidX but it may or may not be the smooth transition for you.
They recommend some of the last versions of their plugins which you can safely use if you don't want to go for the latest AndroidX. I have faced the issue with the `map_view` plugin while upgrading Flutter So I would suggest you to first do it on an isolated environment to see if this works or not.
To know more about the AndroidX, refer this link,
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

For migration refre this,
https://medium.com/@swhussain110/how-to-migrate-your-flutter-app-to-androidx-9a78eaaa924b

Comment: Thanks RopAli, I remember when I tried to install Flutter on a separate SSD and had installed a later version of Flutter than 1.2.1 I was getting AndroidX errors

Answer (score 0):

You can just upgrade your flutter by

```
flutter upgrade
```

And after if you found any issue then you can slove like

```
flutter packages get
```

and all your dependency churn is gone away.